# After filtering master, how do I retrieve stashed changes on the old master?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch, git-stash

I followed [GitHub's instructions for removing sensitive files from a git repository](http://help.github.com/removing-sensitive-data/) because I wanted to remove some binaries that should not have been checked in.

My first invocation of the `git filter-branch` command failed with:

> Cannot rewrite branch(es) with a dirty working directory.

because I had local changes. So, I stashed away these changes with `git stash`, and re-ran the filter-branch command.

I then ran these commands per the GitHub instructions:

```
rm -rf .git/refs/original
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

The removal of the binaries seems to have worked flawlessly. However, when I now type `git stash list`, the stash entry that I added on the old master is not displayed.

All that I have is the output from `git stash` before I executed the filter-branch command the second time:

```
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: a19db18 LOG_MESSAGE
HEAD is now at a19db18 LOG_MESSAGE
```

Also, `a19db18332b19ea41be888eccfc07e6680d8d6dd` was one of the commits that was rewritten.

Is there a way to retrieve the stashed changes?

Comment: Huh, I can't reproduce this - I stash, rewrite all refs, and the stash is still listed. If you check out `refs/originals/heads/master`, can you see the stash again?

Comment: @Jefromi: I ran other commands as per the GitHub instructions. One of these was `git reflog expire --expire=now --all`, which, now that I think about it, might be the reason why the stash entry is no longer available.

Comment: Ah, I see, I didn't look closely enough to see that they really cleaned things away afterwards in those instructions. I'm actually surprised that, after expiring the reflogs, you were still able to find what you needed in them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you can remember the SHA1 hash of the stash commit objects (yes, stashes create commit objects), the stash may be lost.  One option is to use `git fsck --lost-found` and look for dangling commit objects.  You'll then have to go through one by one until you find the one that is your stash.  You can use gitk to view all these commits (see the `git fsck` help page for an example on how to do this) and hopefully find the stash commits more easily.  Once you've found the commits, you can use `git cherry-pick` on each one, clean up any conflicts and then do `git reset HEAD~2` (since there are two commits with each stash).  You should be good to go then.

I've never done a stash and then something as dangerous as filter-branch.  In the future, I'd recommend making an actual commit with your work-in-progress -- perhaps putting it on a new branch.  Then run the dangerous operation.  After that, you can rollback the commit with a mixed reset as above.

Comment: For me, `git fsck --lost-found` returns nothing. Perhaps that is because I ran `git reflog expire --expire=now --all`.

Comment: @Daniel Trebbien: That's strange.  The git stash help page says: "The latest stash you created is stored in refs/stash; older stashes are found in the reflog of this reference and can be named using the usual reflog syntax (e.g. stash@{0} is the most recently created stash, stash@{1} is the one before it, stash@{2.hours.ago} is also possible)." but that would only mean you'd lose stashes other than the most recent.

Comment: What do you know, it's true. The contents of the `.git/refs/stash` file are `db68a3244f1be503343d9ebbd8cdc60b578e670e`. And, getting the log entry for that commit and examining the diff, I see that it's the correct stash entry. That's what I was looking for. Thank you.